# How to update value in array of objects when onchange text is called (in flat list)

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

There is a state value

```
savedData: [
  { key: 'First Name', value: '' },
  { key: 'Last Name', value: '' },
  { key: 'Mobile', value: '' },
  { key: 'Email', value: '' },
  { key: 'Password', value: '' },
  { key: 'Forgot Password', value: '' },
  { key: 'CheckBox1', value: '' },
]
```

Text inputs are in a flat list, each text input is rendered in each cell.
How can I update a value in the array by index when `onChange` of text input is called, *without* using state variables or global variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass the `key` as parameter for `onChange` method

```
onChange={() => this.handleChange("First Name")}
```

and then just update the value.

```
let field = savedDate.find(({key}) => key == key_param);
field.value = ...
```

I'd recommend to use the field's id as key for the `savedData` *state* and just pass the `event.target.id` as parameter.

```
savedData:[
    {key:'firstName',value:''},
    {key:'lastName',value:''},
    {key:'mobile',value:''},
    {key:'email',value:''},
    {key:'password',value:''},
    {key:'forgot Password',value:''},
    {key:'checkBox1',value:''},
 ]

 ...............

 onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e.target.id)}
```